# How do I code Chi square loop code python

Tags: python, chi-squared

Would REALLY appreciate your help in writing a loop code for running chi square function on multiple columns (one group variable).I tried several options I found on line but they all failed, not sure if this is becasue I have NaN values since I am do not know how to incorporate it to the codele)

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
objects_list=df[['Fulm_NF_Neg','HTN','DM','comp_risk_CV1yr']]

for column in objects_list:
    group1 = df.where(df.Sex== 0).dropna()[column]
    group2 = df.where(df.Sex== 1).dropna()[column]

df['p'] = chisquare(df[['Fulm_NF_Neg','HTN','DM','comp_risk_CV1yr']], axis=1)[1]

df['same_diff'] = np.where(df['p'] > 0.05, 'same', 'different')
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: You are creating `group1` and `group2`, but you never use them.  The data for a chisquare has to meet some fairly strict requirements, as the doc page says.  If you have NaNs, you almost certainly need to remove those rows